# CakePHP - How to use SQL NOW() in find conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having trouble getting any find operations to work using the SQL function NOW() in my conditions.

I am effectively trying to build a find query that says:

**Desired SQL:**

```
WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN Promotion.start AND Promotion.end) AND Promotion.active = 1
```

I have tried many combinations but no matter what I do when using NOW() in the condition, it doesn't work because the query Cake builds puts `'` quotation marks around the model fields so they are interpreted by MySQL as a string.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '(NOW() BETWEEN ? AND ?)' => array('Promotion.start', 'Promotion.end'),
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

**CakePHP created SQL:**

Notice the single quotes around the model fields in the BETWEEN(), so they are treated as strings.

```
WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN 'Promotion.start' AND 'Promotion.end') AND `Promotion`.`active` = '1'
```

---

This doesn't work either.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOW() >=' => 'Promotion.start',
        'NOW() <=' => 'Promotion.end',
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

I know why these solutions don't work.  It's because the model fields are only treated as such if they are the array key in the conditions, not the array value.

I know I can get this to work if I just put the whole BETWEEN() condition as a string:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOW() BETWEEN Promotion.start AND Promotion.end',
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

---

Another example of the same problem is, which is simpler to understand:

**Desired SQL:**

```
WHERE Promotion.start > NOW() AND Promotion.active = 1
```

So I try this:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Promotion.start >' => 'NOW()',
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

And again it doesn't work because Cake puts `'` quotations around the NOW() part.

**CakePHP created SQL:**

```
WHERE `Promotion`.`start` > 'NOW()' AND `Promotion`.`active` = '1''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to not use NOW() as its a function and functions don't use indexes. A better solution would be:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "'" . date('Y-m-d') . "' BETWEEN Promotion.start AND Promotion.end",
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

Comment: What do you mean by functions don't use indexes?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support function based indexes. It can't use indexes when the query contains a function (or expression). It has to do a full table scan. Try it with an explain extended and see what indexes it doesn't use ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOW() BETWEEN Promotion.start AND Promotion.end',
        'Promotion.active' => 1
    )
));
```

Comment: What exactly is there to be injected here? There's no user input.

Comment: If it was user data you would be getting the data from request object like: $this->request->data['Promotion']['start']. In the example code I have shown Promotion.start and Promotion.end are just field names being used in the query, there is no user input.